# How to vizualize a websites js dependencies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a website with quite a few external included scripts. Some of them, will load/inject even more resources.

It's easy to gather a list of all requested resources in Chrome, but is it also possible to get insight about *who* requested a file? I know there is the initiator-col, but that helps to understand where one resource comes from. I am looking for something that shows the impact of one resource/provider.